# Why is "were" used in the highlighted relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, subjunctive-mood, sequence-of-tenses, be, irrealis-were

Thank you for taking interest in this question. I have attached below the context of the clause in question to help your understanding.

A full version of the question would be: Why ***were***, instead of *are*/*would be*/*would have been*/*had been*/*can be*, is used here; is it for grammatical accuracy or is it because  only ***were*** can carry certain subtlety that other alternatives cannot?

> For a vaccine to get from phase I to phase III trials in just ten
>   months, as rvsv-zebov did, was unheard of at the time—a startling
>   example of what urgency and organisation can do. Now a repeat
>   performance, ideally taken at an even faster tempo, is the sum of the
>   world’s desire. In the middle of April more people are dying of
>   covid-19 every three days than died of Ebola in west Africa over three
>   years. A vaccine would not just save lives; it would change the course
>   of the pandemic in two separate, if related, ways. It would protect
>   ***those who were vaccinated*** from getting sick; and by reducing the
>   number of susceptible people it would prevent the virus from
>   spreading, thus also protecting the unvaccinated.

Comment: _Are_ and _can be_ would imply that a vaccine for Covid-19 currently exists, which we know isn't the case. _Were_ is shorter and simpler than your other suggestions.

Comment: Note the [related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531731/does-the-highlighted-sentence-use-the-subjunctive-mood) question that led to this.

Comment: If you want to avoid being perplexed by having to choose a verb, it's also possible to rephrase the sentence and drop the pronoun and verb altogether: *It would protect those vaccinated from getting sick …*

Comment: @ Jason Bassford Yes! Thank you. Taking out "who were" would be much more straightforward. But I still want to probe into the textual or logical reason behind the use of "were" here. Could it be a misuse, or is it because of some misunderstanding of the text on the part of me? It is interesting to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford Can I seek your opinion about what "It", as in "It would protect", exactly stands for? Is it for "vaccines in general against any kind of diseases"; or for "a potential vaccine specific to COVID-19"?